# Dynamic site regeneration GatsbyJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, gatsby

I have a website in GatsbyJS that has huge datasets of dynamic data fetched on load of a page via React fetch. The data displayed needs to be semi live (e.g. be refreshed every 5 minutes).

I am wondering how do I achieve SSR speeds with this, because dynamic fetch doesn't cut it. Is it cron scheduled rebuild and if so what happens during the replace of the build folder?

Comment: GatsbyJS may not be the right tool for you, it is made for static content that does not change very frequently, and it's build is a slow and heavy process.
It does not cope well with huge dynamic datasets that change every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service like [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com). They provide a WebHook URL that triggers a build upon querying. You could then have a cron, every 5 minutes, hitting this URL to trigger a rebuild. Netlify handles the build for you, only replacing your site if the build succeeded.

If you want to do it yourself, you can maybe use [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/v1/) - a webserver that has [a plugin for deploying from git](https://caddyserver.com/v1/docs/http.git), similar to how Netlify works (only update site if build succeeds). Note: this is not yet supported by Caddy 2 (current version).

Another option is [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/deployment/), which also builds your site for your, handling failures gracefully (your site is always up, only replaced when the build succeeds).

Answer (score 0):

I think a cron scheduled rebuild is probably your best bet. You may want to check out Gatsby cloud. They have recently added incremental builds, which means that only certain pages get rebuilt. If only a subset of your pages need to be rebuilt that could significantly speed things up. I think what happens during the replace of the build folder depends on where you host your site. Some hosting services like Netlify will probably use some sort of a URL swap to instantaneously replace your old deployment with the new one. If you host it on a regular VPS there will probably be some inconsistencies as the files are copied over/regenerated. Aside from the newly added incremental build feature I think what you're looking for is precisely Gatsby's Achilles heel.